# Ruby on Rails app fetch bounces How to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

is there any possibility to check with the ActionMailer mail function if a mail-address is still alive?

My problem is that I have a ruby on rails application with lots of users, but some of those changed their mail address and now I got lots of mails back. It would be cool If I can check if the mail is still present, and if not I delete the user from Database.

Any Ideas for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending mail and it fails, you can view those if you've configured

```
raise_delivery_errors = true
```

That would go in your `config/environment/development or production.rb`

Sadly though, with `raise_delivery_errors` there's a gotcha:

> This only works if the external email server is configured
>   for immediate delivery.

If you have the option to use something like mailchimp, sendgrid, etc it handles most of this for you - it won't send to bogus emails, it silences them on future mailings and is just a convenient way to manage your email clickthroughs, etc.  Some email services give you a webhook that says "this email bounced" which you can then do something with in your app/database.  Or more primitively, you can download a csv periodically from their portal and update the database.

Comment: Thanks for this informations. I gonna try it out. Yes I know there are services that can do that for me but at the moment I wanna try to do it my self.

Comment: When I do this parameter to true, is there any return value of the mail function which I can decide what I will do with this mail adress?

Comment: sure you'd have to use a rescue block.

Comment: whats a rescue block?